# I'm getting an undefined method for ActiveRecord::Relation. Am I missing something in my models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I'm getting an undefined method when trying to use db relations. Am I missing something in my models?

```
undefined method `hostname' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0x007f571c40ad10>
Extracted source (around line #101):

98:       <% @event.each do |events| %>
99:           <tr>
100:             <td class='timestamp'><%= events.timestamp %></td>
101:             <td class='sensor_name'><%= events.ips_sensors.hostname %></td>
102:             <td class='sig'><%= events.ips_signatures.sig_id %></td>
103:             <td class='sig_class'><%= events.ips_signatures.sig_class %></td>
```

Controller code;

```
class IpsDashboardController < ApplicationController

  def ips_dashboard    
    @event = IpsEvent.all
  end
end
```

Event Table;

```
class IpsEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :signature, :timestamp
  self.table_name = 'event'
  has_many :ips_sensors
  has_many :ips_signatures
end
```

Sensor Table;

```
class IpsSensor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sid, :hostname, :interface
  self.table_name = 'sensor'
end
```

Signature Table;

```
class IpsSignature < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :sig_id, :sig_name, :sig_class_id, :sig_priority, :sig_rev, :sig_gid
  self.table_name = 'signature'
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You’re asking an `IpsEvent` for its `ips_sensors`, which will return a collection of `IpsSensor` models. Presumably an `IpsSensor` has a `hostname`, but the *collection* of them doesn’t.

Either loop over each sensor, or choose one and print its hostname.

You’ll have the same problem with the subsequent lines, where you’re asking the whole collection of `ips_signatures` for an attribute only defined on each model.